# Use of the word 'so'

Tags: punctuation, commas, so

I am confused about using the word 'so'. 
Here is an example.

> I had a fever so I did not go to work.

Question is, in the above sentence, do I really need a comma before 'so'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it necessary to put a comma before 'so' here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/141825/is-it-necessary-to-put-a-comma-before-so-here)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  "So" is separating two sentences that could stand on their own.
It would be more correct to write, "Because I had a fever, I did not go to work."

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to use a comma before “so” when it’s acting as a conjunction to bring two independent clauses together.

You can find more information on Writer Domain [here](http://blog.writersdomain.net/grammar-time-using-a-comma-before-so/). Using that website as a reference, I created two examples for you.

> The principal was sick, so he called out. — Independent, comma is needed.

> The principal pretended to be sick so he wouldn’t have to go to work. — Dependent, no comma is needed.

Comment: If you copied and pasted this information from somewhere you need to make it clear and put quoted words in block quotes.

Comment: Please stop using flags as an expedient to reply to my comments. If you'd like to respond, just leave a comment. You claim in your flag that these are your own words; then how do you explain this: ["_a comma is needed before “so” when it’s acting as a conjunction_"](http://blog.writersdomain.net/grammar-time-using-a-comma-before-so/)

Comment: My apologies, I did not know I had the permissions to leave a comment. I have updated my answer to include the source material.